# Backbone.js el error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm currently learning backbone.js, still in the very beginning but I'm getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined
```

on the line **this.$el.html( template );**

```
<body>
                <div id="search_container"></div>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/template" id="search_template">
                        <label>Search</label>
                        <input type="text" id="search_input" />
                        <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function()
                        {

                                SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
                                initialize: function(){
                                        this.render();
                                },
                                render: function(){
                                        // Compile the template using underscore
                                        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {});
                                        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
                                        this.$el.html( template );
                                }
                                });

                                var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
                        });
                </script>
        </body>
```

Why is this error occuring?

Comment: Try putting the div at the top of your body tag before all the scripts. I think your JavaScript is executing before the div exists.

Comment: You really should be using the latest version of Backbone, 0.3.3 is from the stone ages.

Comment: Seriously, what are you doing using Backbone 0.3.3? And jQuery 1.6.1?

Comment: lool, I was just trying something I took from an old tutorial, really i didn't noticed it, just wanted to make sure it works

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the el element of the view to

```
new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
```

But nowhere in your html is the element already present. This the cause for the error,
as defining el this way means that you have that element already present on the page and assigning the element as the container for the view.

Either add that element to the `HTML` or edit it like below

```
new SearchView();
```

so that the `el` will fall back to a div by default.

Answer (score -1):

When you reference a DOM element in your javascript code, that element have to be already available — the JS code should be run after this element's creation. Here, `#search_container` div that you assing to the view's `el` field is created after the script execution. To avoid such problems, use jQuery's `ready` method:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({

        // ...

    });

    // ...
});
```

This method runs the function passed as the argument after HTML document is created and all elements are ready to use.

Also, the version of backbone that you're using seems not to automatically manage the value of `$el` property. If you need to use this version update the `initialize` method like this:

```
initialize: function()
{                                  
    this.$el = $(this.el);
    this.render();
},
```

This will manually set `$el` to the desired value.

Comment: nopes, same problem, I've edited the question with your suggestion

Comment: Update `underscore` and `backbone` to the recent versions. You'll find the files at http://backbonejs.org/ and http://underscorejs.org/.